# What I should do to have my .apk file?

Tags: android, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I would like to extract my app in .apk format.
I add these script on my "package.json" page:

`"build:development:android": "ionic cordova build android"`

and `"build:production:android": "ionic cordova build android --prod --release"`.

But, when I type the commands I have Errors.
What I should do to have my .apk file?

[image: npm run build:development:android]

[image: npm run build:production:android]

I am novice. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It suggests a couple of solutions for you right after _"typescript error"_. Did you try those? What were the results?

Comment: I am beginner, I have trouble understanding these suggestions, so I would like to know what to do simply..

Answer (score 1):

I think you encounter 2 problems and I will try to refer to them based on the screenshots.

Screenshot #1: I believe this is a permissions error, if you  run the same command as an admin do you have the same result? In order to run it as an admin you will:

- type 'cmd' in your search bar bottom at the windows bar
- when the results emerge, right click on the command line and hit 'run as administrator'

Screenshot #2: This is a code error but it is simple to fix.

- It seems that you have added the Album page via `ionic generate page AlbumPage` but then added that to your app.module.ts.
- The result is that AlbumPage is declared on both app.module.ts and album.module.ts.
- Since AlbumPage is built to be an Ionic Page (if you navigate in album.ts, right above Component annotation, you will se the IonicPage() annotation) you can remove it from the app.module.ts, and wherever you are referring to this page you can use the string of the name e.g. this.setRoot('AlbumPage'), instead of this.setRoot(AlbumPage), which also means that you do not have to import it.

Comment: I delete the files ending with "module.ts" from my pages and the annotations as you told me. But, I don't understand one thing, which page I have to remove from "app.module.ts" are you referring to the page "IonicPage" or "AlbumPage"?

Answer (score 1):

aha! I can see the problem in your code !

you are generating pages from ionic generate command! but if you see the file structure you will find that the page folder has its own module file! first delete that and then go to yourPage.ts file and delete the import of ionicPage and also remove the Annotation of ionic page....   Repeat this step for all pages which have this module file in them!

after that make sure your pages are imported in your app.module.ts

here lemme show you an example how it is done!   consider I have a class called testerClass.  its page structure on using

ionic g page testerClass will be as

[image]

**delete that tester-class.module.ts**

**Step 2**:  AFTER deleting that you have to go into **tester-class.ts** and

remove the annotation and import of ionic page like shown in picture

[image]

**

> NOTE!!make sure you run the build commands using admin/root pre villages (if you are not using root account just in case). in simple words search your cmd in windows search option right click and open as administrator

**

Comment: well now what you should do is to remove the platform of android using ionic Cordova platform rm android! and re Add it! set up your config.xml file like the pkg name you want ! and then use the release command!   and what version of ionic you are on?

Comment: I use ionic 3.20.0  I delete by doing "Cordova platform rm android", what is the command to put it again please "cordova platform add android" ? And, how to configure my config.xml file as you said .. I am a little lost sorry..... :/

Comment: ionic Cordova platform add android will add it!  and please follow the link of ionic document for more! ... in android we call it setting the package name, or in iOS we call it setting your iOS app bundle ! set that please in config.xml of yours!

Comment: The command exact is "cordova platform add android" friend.
Can you show me clearly what is missing from my config.xml page please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176520/discussion-between-rizwan-atta-and-lylys).